# Casting not working well in C

Tags: c, casting

programming C using xcode, here's the f

```
#include <stdio.h>

int multiply (int x, int y) {
return x * y;
}
int main()
{

float result = (float) multiply (0.2, 0.5);
printf("the result is %f", result);

}
```

I don't get the right value, I get 0.0000 !! I did the casting but I don't know whats wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Your program multiplies `0` by `0`.

`multiply` takes two `int` parameters, so your `0.2` and `0.5` are implicitly converted to `int` before making the call.  That truncates both to `0`.

Your typecast doesn't do *anything* in this program, since the return value of `multiply` (which is an `int`) will get implicitly converted during the assignment to `result` anyway.

You need to change the definition of `multiply` (or add a floating-point version and call that) if you want this program to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The `multiply ()` input arguments are `int`:

```
int multiply (int x, int y) {
```

and you have passed `float` as input arguments:

```
multiply (0.2, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi there is a basic problem. As the numbers you are multiplying are floats but you are passing these into the function multiply as int's hence being rounded to 1 and 0.

This should work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int multiply (float x, float y) {
  return x * y; 
}
int main()
{

float result = (float) multiply (0.2, 0.5);
printf("the result is %f", result);
}
```

Comment: your multiply function is defined as int you have to changed to float because you are returning a float (x*y)

Comment: Both parameters to multiply in the original version will be 0. Implicit conversion from float to int truncates rather than rounding.